# Listing all repositories served by git-daemon

Tags: git

Assuming that I know there is a `git-daemon` running at `git://git.mycompany.com`, how can I list all repositories served by that specific instance?

---

*Update*: I don't have shell access to git.mycompany.com.

Comment: Hey @Robert Munteanu, both this answers require some admin changes or access to system dirs of the server. Is there any other way we can list repositories ?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar - not that I know of.

Comment: thanks @Robert Munteanu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one other way but it needs some assistance of you companies server admins.
Git features a browsable web frontend called 'GitWeb' which can be configured to show all projects served by git.

Details are explained in the [GitWeb README](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb#_repositories) - the config key of interest is called
"GITWEB_PROJECTROOT":

> GITWEB_PROJECTROOT
> The root directory for all projects shown by gitweb. Must be set
> correctly for gitweb to find repositories to display.  See also
> "Gitweb repositories" in the INSTALL file for gitweb.

Maybe you could have a talk with you admins - gitweb can be a great profit for all developers.

Comment: Link doesn't work (anymore):

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this needs to be done on the machine that is running `git-daemon`. You either need to check the arguments where `git-daemon` was invoked, or possibly check `/etc/inetd.conf`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have shell access to that machine.