# How to know all projects from remote repository?

Tags: git, ssh

Has there any way to know list of git in remote repository ? If I can know , I would like to download all projects from remote repostiory. Please assume remote repository has

1. projectA.git
2. projectB.git
3. projectC.git

Now I am working on projectA.git and I am not knowing about there also have *projectB.git* and *projectC.git*.

I can clone or fetch data from `ssh://remoteMachine@xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xxx/data/repos/projects/projectA.git`

So, I want see another urls such as ..
 `ssh://remoteMachine@xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xxx/data/repos/projects/projectB.git`
 `ssh://remoteMachine@xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xxx/data/repos/projects/projectC.git`

Can it be possible ?

Comment: Probably not in general. Perhaps your `ssh` gives you some shell access. Then try to run `ls` thru `ssh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with git alone, you need a frontend dedicated application to list the repos.

- A git distribution comes with gitweb, which can list those repos. See "[Listing all repositories served by git-daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1052498/6309)"
- an [authorisation layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/concepts.html) like **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)** will also [list the repos you have access to](https://superuser.com/a/317599/141) (with **[`gitolite info`](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/user.html#info)**).

Note: using `ssh ls` supposes having access to an interactive ssh, which is generally not recommended (because you could execute other commands as well, like... `rm`)